# Perspective Matrix doesn't work OpenGL 4

Tags: opengl, c++, mathematics

I tried to implement my own perspective matrix and it doesn't work. I don't understand why. With just with my view matrix (without Perspective Matrix) I can see my mesh.

Here my view matrix :

```
Vec3f position(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
Vec3f target(0.0,0.0,0.0);

Mat4f Camera::LookAt(Vec3f target, Vec3f position)
{
 //ce dont j'ai besoin pour calculer les parametre de ma camera...
 Vec3f up_world = Vec3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
 Vec3f forward = (position - target).normalize();
 Vec3f right = up_world.cross(forward).normalize();
 Vec3f up = forward.cross(right).normalize();


 Mat3f R;
 R.setCol(2,forward);
 R.setCol(0,right);
 R.setCol(1,up);

 R.transpose();

 Mat4f R4(R);

 Vec3f mp = position * -1.0f;
 Mat4f P4;
 P4.setCol(3,mp);

 _LookAt = R4 *P4;
 return  _LookAt;
}
```

And my Perspective Matrix :

```
Mat4f Camera::perspective(float fovy, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar)
{

  float theta = fovy * 0.5f * (180.f / M_PI);
  float range = zFar - zNear;
  float invtan = 1.f/tanf(theta);

  Mat4f projMat(invtan / aspect,  0.0f,    0.0f,                       0.0f,
                           0.0f,  invtan,  0.0f,                       0.0f,
                           0.0f,  0.0f,    -(zFar + zNear) / range,  -2 * zNear * zFar / range,
                           0.0f,  0.0f,    -1.0f,                      0.0f);

    _perspectiveCam = projMat;
    std::cout << _perspectiveCam << std::endl;
    return _perspectiveCam;
}

  Mat4f perspective(float fovy = M_PI/2, float aspect = (1280.f/720.f)*1.f, float zNear = 0.1f, float zFar = 100.f);
```

My shader is very simple so it can't be the problem..

```
#version 410 core


layout(location = 0) in vec3 V_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 V_color;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 V_normal;


uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;


out vec3 color;
void main()
{
    color = V_color;
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * view_matrix * vec4(V_position, 1.);
}
```

when I initialise _perspectiveCam with the unit matrix 4x4 it displays my triangle..
but when I implement _perspectiveCam like in the function it does not display my triangle

Here my Set col function :

```
template <typename TYPE>
void Mat4<TYPE>::setCol(int i, Vec4<TYPE>& vec4)
{
  for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; k++)
  {
    setElement(k,i, vec4.getElement(k));
  }

}

void setElement(int i,int j, TYPE var){element[i*4 + j] = var;}
TYPE getElement(int i, int j) const {return element[i*4 + j];}
```

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. I suggest editing to include the shader as well. Even simple code can hide errors. And if it is simple, it won't take much room.

Comment: My long and bitter experience tells me: everytime somebody says "it can't be the problem" - it turns out to actually be the problem.  So yes, you should post your shader too.

Comment: haha maybe, sorry for my late response i did not have connection i will edit my post with the shader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: *"It doesn't work"* is not very descriptive. What are you observing? A black screen? Distorted geometry?

Next: What is the convention for your Mat4f class? Can you show setCol() implementation? Is your translation part stored in [3],[7],[11] or [12],[13],[14]?

Because I suspect that your projmat may have flipped col/row?

In my implementation, the projmat (same values as yours) is laid out differently, like so:

```
    mout[0] = f / aspect;
    mout[1] = 0.0f;
    mout[2] = 0.0f;
    mout[3] = 0.0f;

    mout[4] = 0.0f;
    mout[5] = f;
    mout[6] = 0.0f;
    mout[7] = 0.0f;

    mout[8] = 0.0f;
    mout[9] = 0.0f;
    mout[10] = (zFar+zNear) / (zNear-zFar);
    mout[11] = -1.0f;

    mout[12] = 0.0f;
    mout[13] = 0.0f;
    mout[14] = 2 * zFar * zNear /  (zNear-zFar);
    mout[15] = 0.0f;
```

And after doing `proj * view * model`, I feed it into the shader with `glUniformMatrix4fv()`.

In my shader, I post-multiply the position, like so:

```
gl_Position = modelcamviewprojmat * position;
```

My matrix class has translation in [12], [13], [14]

The things I would try:

1. Switch multiplication order, to see if it helps: sometimes it is model * view * proj, sometimes it is proj * view * model.
2. Make sure the layout of your proj matrix, above, is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have forgotten to transpose  my lookAt and perspective Matrix.. I thought Open GL works with column major matrix but apparently it 's not the case .. So thank you